# Double Google Analytics Tag in Tag Asisstant

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I installed Google Analytics code 1 time on the site through GTM. Why is it showing me 2 tag in Tag Asisstant ? The code is set correctly, 1 PageViews is passed to Google Analytics. Nothing is passed to gtag.js, but it shows up ... Why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tags you are seeing in Google Tag Assistant is expected behaviour regarding Global Site Tag (gtag.js). Global Site Tag is a tagging JS framework and API. With the code snippet being comprised of two script tags. In this instance you have it configured for GA tracking...hence the GA tag as well.
[image: screenshot of source code showing gtag.js tracking code snippet]

I notice you also have Google Tag Manager installed. You could remove the Global Site Tag code version of the GA tracking and use GA tags within GTM for configuring your GA tracking.

Comment: I have only one google analytics tag on site installed through GTM using Google Analytics - Universal Analytics Tag. But it shows that there are 2. I was surprised

Comment: That would appear to not be the case. Is UA-64146581-1 the correct GA Property? What is the website address?

Comment: There is a gtag.js tracking code snippet installed (added screenshot from source code to my reply), it appears to be sending pageviews for GA. Not seeing any pageviews fire via GTM, however I am seeing scroll tracking events fire GTM

Comment: If you remove the gtag code, then there will be only 1 tag in the Tag Assistant and will everything be tracked correctly?

Comment: You would need to ensure you have a pageview tag correctly configured and firing withing GTM

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted to understand why exactly two tags are a double (screenshot)? Is there somewhere a code that needs to be removed from the site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217226/discussion-between-bronwyn-v-and-mr-robot).